# Can Jim Berkland predict earthquakes?

Tags: geology

Jim Berkland [claims](http://mychurchofme.com/2011/03/former-usgs-geologist-jim-berkland-predicts-major-california-quake/) that he can predict earthquakes. Can he or other people predict earthquakes better than chance?

Comment: No, if you watch the video, he is being very specific about the date range, March 19th - 26th. "Could" is my summarizing of his statements within the news clip, as the author of the post, but should not be taken as his words. His are very specific.

Answer (score 4):

This is certainly something that could be tested, but it would be hard.  You would have to define the conditions for it to be meaningful, including

1. How many predictions will he make?
2. How close does he have to be to the epicenter?
3. How close does he have to be in magnitude?
4. What time frame counts?
5. etcetera

"the next big earthquake along the ring of fire could be as early as this weekend." is rather broad.  ANY earthquake of ANY magnitude ANYWHERE along the ENTIRE ring of fire counts?  And if one doesn't happen, well he did just say it COULD happen.  They only way he looses is if there is a big earthquake BEFORE this weekend - and even then he'd probably still claim he was correct.